# How to get working Qt mysql driver?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I want connect to mysql with Qt. i tested few methods that aren't work i wrote these code:

```
C:\QtSDK\QtSources\4.8.1\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:\\Pr
ogram Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\include" "LIBS+=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\
MySQL Server 5.6\\lib\\libmysql.lib" mysql.pro

C:\QtSDK\QtSources\4.8.1\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>make
make -f Makefile.Debug all
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mys
ql'
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICO
DE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_DLL
 -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MM
XEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I'../../../../include/QtCore' -I'../../
../../include/QtSql' -I'../../../../include' -I'c:/Program' -I'Files/MySQL/MySQL
' -I'Server' -I'5.6/include' -I'../../../../include/ActiveQt' -I'tmp/moc/debug_s
hared' -I'../../../../mkspecs/win32-g++-4.6' -o tmp/obj/debug_shared/main.o main
.cpp
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-fno-keep-inline-dllexport
"
```

and this is my error:

```
make[1]: *** [tmp/obj/debug_shared/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysq
l'
make: *** [debug-all] Error 2
```

Comment: I only see one error, and only the last part of the error message, which is non-informative.

Comment: The actual error message is somewhere above what you posted. There's no way to even guess as to what's wrong with what you posted. Please [edit] your post to add more of that log.

Comment: I changed the post, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Well, I myself struggled a lot compiling Qt MySql plugin on Windows. So here is my suggestion:
use ODBC gateway to your MySql base: ODBC plugin has no compilation problems when building Qt; MySql ODBC connector can be downloaded from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc

Sorry, it's not quite an answer to your question, but will let you keep going at least.

Comment: I installed ODBC and wrote this code : QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("test");
    db.setPassword("");
    db.setUserName("root");
    if (!db.open()){
     qDebug() << "Error opening database";
     return -1;
    } else {
     return 0;
    } but it can not open the connection

Comment: anyway i have both xampp and mySql database also my database name is 'test' with 'books' table and I use localhost and 'root' user.

Comment: @user1695063 You have to configure correctly your database in ODBC Data Source Administrator (in Control Panel). Be sure you pass the connection test (click 'Test' button).

Comment: I have XP and my database name is 'test' and my table is 'books' but i dont know what i must  write in ODBC Data Source Configuration, would you tell me more details OR show me a tutorial about setting ODBC in Qt step by step?

Comment: @user1695063 In ODBC Data Source Config you have to add new Used DSN, choose MySQL ODBC driver. Thne you choose you data source name (the one will be referenced in your Qt application as DB name), and provide TCP/IP parameters + user/password + database to connect to your MySQL database. At this point you can click 'Test' button to check the connection.

Comment: i determined Data Source to 'DB', TCP/IP to 'localhost', both username and passwrod to '1' then when I cilck on Test button show me this message box: Connection faile: [HY000][MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a)Driver]Access denied for user '1'@'localhost'(using password:YES),What must i do now?

Comment: @user1695063 For the parameters you specified I suppose you have MySQL server installed on localhost, with user name and password set to '1'. If it's not the case the ODBC gateway won't be able to connect obviously. You have to use exactly the same parameters you would use for mysql console client or any other client.